# How to determine the fees when using a Dutch bank card overseas?

Tags: banking, money-transfer, currency, credit-cards

I want to use my Netherlands credit card overseas, to withdraw money in local currency in some non-European states (specifically: USA, Israel).

- What are, or how do I determine, the (typical) fees and conversion rate for doing this?
- Are all credit cards, by all banks / credit card companies in the Netherlands, the same with respect to these fees and exchange rates?

If you'd like to answer more specifically about one bank/credit card: I'm with ABN-AMRO, and I have an ICS MasterCard of theirs.

Comment: The fees for mine are stated clearly in the terms and conditions, I assume it must be the same for others. A quick google search suggests the fees do differ, quite a bit (from 1.5% to 4% for a withdrawal with a credit card, charges with a credit card or withdrawal with a debit card are cheaper). For credit cards, the conversion course is determined by Visa and/or Mastercard and your bank's fees are applied to that rate.

Comment: There's probably at least a dozen banks with different terms and conditions. Please clarify which bank you personally have or ask a more targeted question.

Comment: @JonathanReez: I wasn't asking about actual feels but about their uniformity and how you determine fees. But I'll oblige...

Comment: I am still not sure this is a good question (it states so plainly in the terms and conditions and has very little to do with expatriation) but: [conditions for your debit card](https://www.abnamro.nl/nl/images/Content/010_Prive/020_Producten_l_diensten/020_Betalen/1613313/pdf_Informatieblad_Betaaldiensten_Particulieren_(2016-02-16_15_060_165).pdf) (p. 6) and [your credit card](https://www.abnamro.nl/nl/images/Content/010_Prive/020_Producten_l_diensten/020_Betalen/1613313/pdf_Informatieblad_Betaaldiensten_Particulieren_(2016-02-16_15_060_165).pdf) (article 13).

Comment: There are a bunch of special cases but for the regular BetaalPacket and credit card (not gold or anything), withdrawing foreign currency with your debit card should cost you €2.25 plus a 1.2% commission. There are a few subtleties regarding which exchange rate is used, it's always in the ballpark but I have never been able to recompute it myself. Withdrawing money with a credit card is so expensive that I never tried.

Comment: Putting on hold as you've got multiple questions in the post,. If you can edit to just one per post, please then flag it and I can reopen.